# tesseract OCR not 100% accurate

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract

I need to scan a handwritten font. I am using tesseract OCR v3.02 for that. I have trained my OCR using box files and adding dictionary words as well but still I am not able to get 100% accuracy.

[I am trying to scan the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxLR4.png)

So far the text file i am obtaining is like this:

*We each took baths before bed. Bigfoot was so large that he had to use the bathtub more like a sink trying to clean
up his best. he left a pool of water around the usa It was a mess and I mopped it and removed all of the fur
left behind before taking a bath of my Own. I have to admit it was cguite disgusting. “It”s cguite simple.” Me
assured her. “Mere, I”ll show you.”Iimmy‘s was the favorite burger joint among us kids. Sreat burgers. and
there were video games and pinball machines. Jimmy”s has been around since the fift"es. all our parents used to
go there when they were young. “‘Mot exactly.""Another blanket. Ben. please."“I really hope so. because I feel so*

Any help to improve the the OCR?

Comment: so far i have trained the tesseract OCR engine using jTessBoxEditor(http://vietocr.sourceforge.net/training.html) and i have also added english dictionary words as training data.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't mean anything to me, but crafting exactly what you've done into your question will be helpful to your would be answerers.